# Weblogic автоматическое создание Topics

Tags: java, weblogic, jms

На данный момент занимаюсь Weblogic JMS. Все работает, но возник следующий вопрос. У меня создано 5 Topic'ов сейчас. Однако, их кол-во будет расти и их может быть 20+. Есть ли возможность программно создать Topic и настроить их?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите вот это [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createTopic(java.lang.String)).

Но вообще (что, кстати, указано в приведенной ссылке) создание JMS-объектов невозможно

PS. В 1.7 это более подробно [описано](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/JMSContext.html#createTopic(java.lang.String))